# How can I hide the WebView until the website's finished logining? [react native]

Tags: javascript, webview, react-native

I'm trying to make a component that display a website with `WebView` and then auto-fill the user information to login. I took care the auto-fill part by injecting some javascript into the `WebView` with the `injectedJavascipt` prop.  
But the thing is I want to hide the `WebView` (the sign-in page), show a loading screen and only display it when the user is logged into the website. Since I can't interact with the website in any way, my workaround is to set the `flex` prop of the `WebView` to 0 and when the login complete, set it to 1 using `setNativeProps()`.  
Is there anyway for me to know when the website has finished logining so I can then show the `WebView`? If not, is there any other way to hide my `WebView` and display it when that website's done logining?  
tl;dr: basically i want my `WebView` to load some stuffs in the background while some loading screens are displayed and signal me when those things are done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hacky but maybe you could check for the URL when the user is fully logged in and then change the flex property?

```
navChanged(navState) {
    if(navState.url.match(loggedInURL){
      //set flex to 1
    };
  }
<WebView
  source={{uri: this.state.url}}
  onNavigationStateChange={this.navChanged}
  startInLoadingState={true}
  renderLoading={
    ()=> {
      return (<ActivityIndicator /> )
    }
  }
/>
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, I misread the question. I updated my answer, would that help? Does the URL change when the user is successfully logged in?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself but I think something like the following should do what you want. The WebView has loading related props like `onLoad`, `onLoadStart`, `onLoadEnd`, `onError`, etc. In those you can update your component's state. Whenever you call `this.setState`, the component's `render()` is triggered again and based on the current state it will render the View you tell it to.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            isLoading:false
        }
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return <Spinner visible={true}/>
        } else 
            return <WebView onLoadStart={() => this.setState({isLoading:true})} onLoadEnd={() => this.setState({isLoading:false})}/>
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you I tried but the sign-in page still showed. The WebView doesn't consider injectedJavascript a part of it's loading state. Is there a  way to change isLoading when injectedJavascript finishes?

Comment: Isn't in this way the WebView actually not loaded?