# React Native - Headless Browser Automation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, headless

I have an app that needs to scrape some data from websites which contain JavaScript.  With NodeJS, this is easy with puppeteer or playwright.  With React Native, I can use fetch or axios to request the html of the page, but the Javascript will not be executed.

I have learned of a npm package which can allow me to use NodeJS with React Native on Android or iOS (https://github.com/JaneaSystems/nodejs-mobile-react-native).  But since puppeteer or playwright normally automate a desktop version of Chrome, is there any way to achieve similar functionality on mobile devices?

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if this doesn't help directly, just seeding an idea.

**Why not use a Webview to render the content, then retrieve the web page data?**

You *might* be able to affect the Webview's /size/visibility/flex-ccs-style to 'hide' it but I'm not sure exactly how much mileage you can get from each of those techniques.

There *are* articles covering ways of hiding Views (e.g. containing Webviews) and on-webpage-load events (if you want to get a call back, once the page is rendered). I'm planing on doing something similar, hopefully, here are some useful articles to help:

- [How can I hide the React-Native WebView until the website's finished logging in?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39908115)
- [WebView loading state manipulation](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5974#issuecomment-404659758) (includes 'flex: 0' style/size handling)
- [Hide a component by un-mounting](https://medium.com/scripbox-engineering/how-to-hide-a-view-component-in-react-native-8a4994382c0) (not rendering), rather than mounting and mutating the opacity or position (Medium.com)
- [Component Refs and the DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-dom-element) (React-Native @Facebook)
- [Accessing refs in a custom component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49810837) (StackOverflow)

See if any of the above is helpful.